# Where are pthreads in Gforth?

Tags: forth, gforth

I am trying to load the [PThreads](https://bernd-paysan.de/gforth-manual/Pthreads.html) module in Gforth. It appears to be unavailable.

```
needs pthread.fs
:1: No such file or directory
needs >>>pthread.fs<<<
Backtrace:
$7F647BA86F40 throw
$7F647BA87048 required
needs pthreads.fs
:2: No such file or directory
needs >>>pthreads.fs<<<
Backtrace:
$7F647BA86F40 throw
$7F647BA87048 required
needs unix/pthreads.fs
:3: No such file or directory
needs >>>unix/pthreads.fs<<<
Backtrace:
$7F647BA86F40 throw
$7F647BA87048 required
needs unix/pthread.fs
:4: No such file or directory
needs >>>unix/pthread.fs<<<
Backtrace:
$7F647BA86F40 throw
$7F647BA87048 required
```

I am running Gforth `0.7.0`. Is there anything special I need to do to load it? Is it only available in a newer version?

After some googling, it appears that it is [probably in a version higher than 0.7.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.forth/r2y_DaFQtxA).